# How to perform a search query both in Turkish and English language

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to perform a search which searches for both languages. I am using `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` on my query to perform this action.

For instance I want to search for "ağaç". It doesn't work, plus I get a warning; `Warning: COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'` But my character set is not `latin1`, I am using `utf8_turkish_ci`

What I basically want to do is both search for "agac" and "ağaç".

Here is my query

```
$searchQ = "select ".$options.", ".DB_PREFIX."users.name as owner,
MATCH (title,description,tags) AGAINST ('".$searchKey."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('".$searchKey."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance FROM ".DB_PREFIX."videos LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."users ON ".DB_PREFIX."videos.user_id = ".DB_PREFIX."users.id 
WHERE MATCH (title,description,tags) AGAINST('".$searchKey."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND ".DB_PREFIX."videos.pub > 0 and ".DB_PREFIX."videos.date < now() $interval COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ORDER by title_relevance DESC,relevance DESC ".this_limit();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add this after your MySQL connection : $db -> exec ("set names utf8"); And you can also you utf8_unicode_general_ci for almost all kind of characters :p

Comment: @Soheyl Thank you for the answer, I've tried it before and just to make sure tried it again, but it still same :-/

Comment: Change your table character to utf8_unicode_general_ci and also try the search with "agac", let's see if it's work :)

Comment: @Soheyl I've tried both `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_general_ci`, still no change

Comment: even with only using "agac" ?

Comment: @Soheyl Unfortunately yes, when I search for "ağaç" it only shows the results contains "ağaç", but when I do search for "agac", nothing appears. Ive double, triple checked the collations and queries but I still couldn't understand what is wrong

Comment: Try with default character and search for "agac"